# What is this weed called and how to kill it apart from hand pulling

Tags: weeds

Need help with weed identification. I have tried weed killer like Scott’s weed and doesn’t work

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Is this from your lawn or the borders/beds?

Comment: It looks like a grass species, so broad-leaf weedkillers including "lawn weedkillers" won't affect it. Hard to tell the exact species from your picture.

Comment: Definitely a grass.  I advise trying to find an online grass identification tool for your area.  I have had great success with this method.  Sadly, if it is quackgrass, I am not sure if any selective herbicide is available.

Comment: It looks more like barley than couch grass to me. It could have acquired herbicide resistance from a domesticated variety. Are you near farmland?

Comment: @Separatrix Barley *is* a species of grass, so it has the same natural resistance to broad leaf weed killers as any other type of grass. There are several "wild" species of barley as well as the cultivated varieties (which have been genetically modified by humans for about 4,000 years before Monsanto got a bad reputation for doing it!).

Comment: This is from my lawn and not flowerbed. I am not near any farms. I was thinking that this may be dallisgrass, bahia or crab grass but not sure.

Comment: I have added more pictures

Comment: It's definitely not couch grass/quackgrass, the seed heads are completely different. Best guess is that it's a barley variant, there's a good chance you'll kill your lawn before you find a weedkiller that will target it as it's still a grass and there's still a risk of it being a broad spectrum herbicide resistant variety.

Answer (score 2):

Dig it up and either re-seed or fill the hole with a piece of turf. This is the message behind the previous comments and it's what I do when I get it.